# Node not talking with Postgres Database after using Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, docker, containers

Im very new to Docker. I'm trying to dockerize a very simple to do app build with react, node/express and postgret. I've been reading a bunch of articles and looking at solutions here in stackoverflow and still cannot figure out why my app is not working. When I run docker-compose up -d, it builds a cluster with three containers. Perfect so far good, however when i check the app and try to add a new todo i see a message in the server container `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`. I'm not sure What I need to do to have the app running like it should. I really appreciate any help.

this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```js
version: '3'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12.1
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Elchido10
            POSTGRES_USER: juancastillo
            POSTGRES_DB: perntodo
        volumes:
            - ./postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks: 
            - todo-app
    server:
        image: todo_server
        environment: 
            DB_HOST: host.doceker.internal
            DB_USER: juancastillo
            DB_PASS: Elchido10
            DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:pgpassword@db:5432/perntodo
        
        build:
            context: ./server
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./server/config:/app/config
            - ./server/src:/app/src
            - ./server/test:/app/test
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        depends_on: 
            - postgres
        networks: 
            - todo-app
    client:
        image: todo_client
        stdin_open: true
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./client:/app
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        networks: 
            - todo-app
        
networks: 
    todo-app:
        driver: bridge
```

this is how i am connecting to the database:

```js
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "juancastillo",
  password: "Elchido10",
  host: "postgresdb",
  post: 5432,
  database: "perntodo"
})

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: where is the localhost address of your error message coming from? clearly `DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:pgpassword@db:5432/perntodo` tells a different story (using the service name, as you should).

Comment: @GutZuFusss sorry i dont understand what you mean by localhost address of my error coming from

Comment: should i delete this: DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:pgpassword@db:5432/perntodo

Comment: i am talking about this: `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`